# If not taking into account data characteristics, are longer sequences generally harder for an LSTM-model to classify?

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I understand that LSTM architectures are purposed for sequential data where an understanding of *context* could positively contribute to a prediction.

But if leaving this factor out (or, i.e., assuming that no context can be learnt from the data), would it be safe to assume that generally, processing larger sequences is harder than shorter sequences?

If it is not generally harder, is it true that it is at least not "generally easier" to handle longer sequences? What if one would perform 5 experiments on a dataset with samples of varied lengths and create groups of samples of a fixed size (i.e., 1K samples with sequence length 5, 1K with 10... up to length 25; so, all very short sequence lengths, relative to the norm) and train 5 separate LSTMs with the same architecture on each of the groups and evaluate them on test set held out from these groups. Then, if one would observe performance to be higher for longer sequence lengths, could one safely conclude that for my exact data, longer sequences add more valuable contextual information? Since, if it would be the opposite way around, and performance decreases when sequence length increases significantly, one could probably argue that the sequence length poses a limitation. So, I am basically asking if the opposite does not hold.